# having trouble of sorting list in python

Tags: python, sorting

```
a=[(' ', '000'), ('\n', '001000'), ('v', '00100100'), ('O', '0010010100'),('e', '110'), ('n', '1110'), ('r', '1111')]
```

and i want to sort the list first by the length of the number and then for the alphabetical order of all character that have the same length of number. i have tried to sort by for loop but it just sorts my length of number and not for alphabetical order.

```
a=[(' ', '000'), ('\n', '001000'), ('v', '00100100'), ('O', '0010010100'),('e', '110'), ('n', '1110'), ('r', '1111')]
for i in range (len(a)):
    for j in range(1,len(a)):
        if len(a[i][1])>len(a[j][1]):
            swap = a[i]
            a[i]=a[j]
            a[j]=swap
```

does anyone have any idea ??? thanks in advance

Comment: Is this for a class? Python has a few sort methods built in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `key` argument to `sort`:

```
a.sort(key=lambda item: (len(item[1]), item[0]))
```

Or more verbosely:

```
def sort_func(item):
    return len(item[1]), item[0]

a.sort(key=sort_func)
```

Comment: @TommyNgo: See if the more verbose way of writing it helps.

Comment: @TommyNgo: I'm not sure how else to explain it. It sorts each element by using the output of `sort_func(element)` instead of the element itself.